# Google script spreadsheet string manipulation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script in google spreadsheet. It's very interesting but I have one issue. I would like to work with a string. I'm getting a cell with text and in this text I would like to make a modification. I would like to remove some space, find and replace some characters or add more text.

I searched how to do that and found nothing.

So I would like to know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

string operations search() and replace() would work here, either can use regular expressions for the effect you are looking for. Full article detailing this is available [here](https://scriptingwithshiva.blogspot.com/2018/04/google-apps-script-regular-expressions.html)
e.g.

```
var inputString = "This is string example....wow!!! this is really string."; 
var outputString = inputString.replace(/ is /g, ' was ');
Logger.log(outputString);
```